# Java File Single Writer, Single reader

Tags: java, io

I;m looking for a very basis IPC mechanism between Java programs. I prefer not to make use of sockets because my 'agent' is spawning new JVM's and setting up sockets in such an environments is a bit more complicated.

I was thinking about having 2 files per spawned JVM: in and out. On the in, the agent sends commands to the worker. And on the out, the worker sends back a response back to the agent.

The big problem is that till so far I didn't manage to get the communication up and running. Just creating ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream doesn't work out of the box, because the readObject method isn't blocking. It will throw an EOFException when there is no content instead instead of blocking. Luckily that was easy to fix, by adding a delay and trying again a bit later.

So I got my POC up and running, but eventually I ran into a stream corruption issue. So apparently, even in append only mode, you still can run into corruption issue. So I started to look at the FileLock, but I'm running now into a ""main" java.lang.Error: java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor".

So till so far the 'lets do the simple file thing' has been quite an undertaking and I'm not sure if I'm in the right path at all. I don't want to introduce a heavy weight solution like JMS or a less heavyweight solution like sockets. Does anyone know something extremely simple that solves this particular problem? My preference is still for a file based approach.

Comment: Does agent JVM span the worker JVM, or are the two started up independently?

Comment: I am wondering if this is an XY Problem. Can you elaborate more on why "setting up sockets in such an environment is a bit more complicated"?  Using files in the way you are attempting to use them seems complicated.

Comment: The Agent JVM spawns the Workers JVM's.

Comment: The reason I didn't pick sockets from the beginning was that the system I'm setting up, is meant to stress/break worker processes by causing all kinds of problems. E.g. OOME, networking etc. In such a situation a file based approach is less problematic than a socket based approach.

Comment: How about using System.in/out of the worker JVM? If the agent JVM spawns a worker JVM via a `runtime.exec()` call, the agent JVM can get a reference to the System.in/out of the worker JVM. You can read/write commands via those streams.

Comment: Hmmm.. that sounds like a very simple solution :) I wished I came up with that before I refactored the code to use sockets. Can you add it as an answer, then I'll give you credits for it.

Comment: One thing I need to check if the stream is a blocking stream. File based streams are not blocking when there is no data, socket based streams are.

Comment: Another potential problem is that the System.out could already be used to output all kinds of info I don't control. Imagine that someone does  a system.out somewhere deep down in my worker JVM...